# How to configure APP CENTER app key on android and iOS projects in Xamarin forms for different environment?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Currently, we proivde the **App Secret key** on the AppCenter.Configure method. This is same for all the different environments.

How can we configure the **App Secret Key** so that I can enter diffrent **App Secret keys** for different environments?

For e.g. **If I need to have different App Secret Key for UAT and Production based on configuration.**

Comment: Can you please provice some example code? What do you like to acchieve, what is the expected outcome, what is the error (if there is any) or the (wrong) result of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create two files, which contains your secrets to appcenter. Don't forget to set build action as Embeded Resource.

```
appsettings.debug.json
appsettings.release.json
```

These file will have this content:

```
{
  "AppCenterKey": "super secret key"
}
```

Then you can load your file regarding to build configuration with this method:

```
        private static void LoadAppSettings()
        {
#if RELEASE
            var appSettingsResourceStream = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(AppSettings)).GetManifestResourceStream("AppSettingsPoC.Configuration.appsettings.release.json");
#else
            var appSettingsResourceStream = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(AppSettings)).GetManifestResourceStream("AppSettingsPoC.Configuration.appsettings.debug.json");
#endif
            if(appSettingsResourceStream == null)
                return;

            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(appSettingsResourceStream))
            {
                var jsonString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                appSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppSettings>(jsonString);
            }
        }
```

Your AppSettings will store the key and it might look like this:

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public string AppCenterKey { get; set; }
}
```

I did the same in my project [following this article](https://onthefencedevelopment.com/2019/10/16/appsettings-in-xamarin-forms/).

Comment: That works, but i'd much rather have the app settings files outside and only placed during deployment. Release pipelines change all the time, App Center keys change all the time. Putting it as a string makes it easily sniffed, so your not saving much on security.

Comment: I do this for both using Cake, this way i'm using the same code base and manipulate the code signing with the app settings file.